# How to pull details from two tables and match values

Tags: mysql, lookup-tables

Two tables, `pondtemp (temp,tempdate,temptime,sensornumber,timeentered)` `sensordetails(sensordescription,senesor number,sensormac)`.

I want to pull details from `pondtemp` and where `pondtemp` returns a sensor number I want to lookup that number on `sensordetails` and return the description.

I have this so far, which works apart from the lookup for the sensor details it lists the sensor details one by one where it shouldn't?

```
use ponddb;
SELECT sensorno, avg(temp) as avgtemp, sensordescription
FROM pondtemp, sensordetails
WHERE tempdate = CURDATE()
GROUP BY tempdate, sensorno, sensordescription
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use mysql joins to get your expected result.

```
SELECT 
T1.sensorno, 
AVG(T1.temp) as avgtemp, 
T2.sensordescription
FROM 
pondtemp T1 
INNER JOIN sensordetails T2 
      ON T1.sensorno = T2.sensorno 
WHERE 
T1.tempdate = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY T1.tempdate, T1.sensorno
```

Not sure this is what you need.

Comment: Hey Fortune, no it didnt work, what im trying to do is list the sensor description so that sensor 1 matches the description

Comment: IE in table sensordetails 1 matches main pond and when I pull data from pondtemp and it shows sensor 1 I want to display main pond

Comment: in case you can change the T1.sensorno to T2.sensorno. Is it?

Comment: SELECT 
sensordetails.sensorno, 
AVG(temp) as avgtemp, sensordescription
FROM 
pondtemp sensordetails 
INNER JOIN sensordetails pondtemp 
      ON sensordetails.sensorno = sensorno 
WHERE 
tempdate = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY sensordetails.tempdate, sensordetails.sensorno this give me the same sensor description per line  - its close but is not matching sensor 1 from pondtemp to sensornum from sensordescription